# specific button close the app when clicked

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

the app keeps closed when i clicked **sign in** button i think the error is from the code but i dont know where is the error exactly

any help!

just this button kick me from he app, other buttons works good!

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button userlogin;
    FirebaseAuth firebseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        username = findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        password = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        userlogin = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

        firebseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firebseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    startActivity(new Intent(login.this,profile.class));
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(login.this,"hellow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }
}`
```

Comment: You can loot at the logs and determine what the error is.

Comment: @Sergey i found that if the username or password is empty and  click the button the app will close. any help with this!

Comment: just check if username and password strings are not empty, then make request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if username and password strings are not empty, then make request:

```
String passwordStr = password.getText().toString() 
String usernameStr = username.getText().toString() 
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordStr) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(usernameStr) {
    firebseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(usernameStr, passwordStr).addOnCompleteListener(....)
}
```

It seems `firebseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` throws an exception if strings are empty.

Comment: thanks that works!